# Z-sets in the Hilbert cube

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then we say that a closed subset $A$ of $X$ is a z-set if for each number $k\gt 0$ there is a continuous map $f_k$ from $X$ into $X-A$ such that $d(x,f_k(x))\lt k$.

I am wondering if an AR  which is a z-set in the Hilbert cube is a deformation retract of it?

Comment: This is false even for finite-dimensional cubes: just take any non-contractible subset of the boundary as your $A$ (like $A=$ a 2-point set). 

Comment: I am sorry, i edit the question

Comment: (I may be confused but in my opinion:) Every retract $X$ of any Hilbert cube $H$ is its deformation retract, i.e. $X$ is a deformation retract of $H$.